# how to authenticate with httparty?

Tags: ruby, linkedin-api, httparty

I'am trying to query LinkedIn with Httparty, but it returns an 401 error :

```html
<error>
  <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1438869780537</timestamp>
  <request-id>1JWX1OVLFT</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Unknown authorization header {Basic cmVteXVram9iQGdtYWlsLmNvbTptdW5kZDIwMTQ=}</message>
</error>
```

I do not know how to login to LinkedIn with httparty.

My script:

```html
require 'httparty'
  
  auth = {:username => "email@gmail.com", :password => "password"}
 @blah = HTTParty.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=[sap]", 
                     :basic_auth => auth)
```

I followed several tutorials, but no luck. In the code above it use my login, but I think I should use Api key

Thanks.

Comment: To add headers you can do something like this :
HTTParty.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=[sap]", :basic_auth => auth, :headers => { "X-ApiKey" => "THISISMYAPIKEYNOREALLY"}))

Comment: @Khanad, sould I use "HTTParty.get("api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=[sap]";, :basic_auth => auth, :headers => { "X-ApiKey" => "Apiuser","apipass"})), as it is user and password key. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am not sure what the exact parameters are that linked in expects. I was merely providing a way to add headers if that is what you needed

Answer (score 1):

I their [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) they write:

> At LinkedIn, we value the integrity and security of our members' data
>   above all else.  In order for your applications to access LinkedIn
>   member data and/or act on their behalf, they must be authenticated. 
>   LinkedIn relies on the industry standard OAuth 2.0 protocol for
>   granting access, due to its simplicity and ease of implementation.
>
> Please read our [Authenticating with OAuth 2.0](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) guide for a detailed
>   walk-through of how to get your application authenticated and
>   successfully interacting with LinkedIn's REST APIs.

Did you read that guide about OAuth?

Comment: @axel_Testzlaff I thought that OAuth was only when you to allow user to user their linkedin credentials. I just want to make simple script. Thanks for your reply.